# Firebase not working on Apple Watch Extension

Tags: swift, firebase

I have been attempting to make an Apple Watch extension and WatchKit app with my firebase application, but every time I make a connection in the extension code, the watch crashes. By connection I mean adding an observer to my Firebase reference. Is firebase not compatible on Apple Watch extensions? Or is there something in firebase that Apple prevents on watches (something like web sockets) that firebase won't be able to work around?

Comment: Watch Extensions and Firebase will work. I'm releasing documentation on the two soon. Could you post the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/libraries/watchkit/guide.html